# How to correctly use the "MMM" parse token in Arrow Python

Tags: python, arrow-python

I've got a number of datetimes in a spreadsheet that look like this:

```
July 29, 2022 @ 9:44 AM
Aug 2, 2022 @ 6:30 PM
...
```

I'm attempting to parse these with the following but I get an exception:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> myformat = "MMM D, YYYY @ H:MM A"
>>> arrow.get("Aug 2, 2022 @ 11:37 PM", myformat)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\enricojr\Projects\python-lox\.venv\lib\site-packages\arrow\api.py", line 91, in get
    return _factory.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enricojr\Projects\python-lox\.venv\lib\site-packages\arrow\factory.py", line 295, in get
    dt = parser.DateTimeParser(locale).parse(
  File "C:\Users\enricojr\Projects\python-lox\.venv\lib\site-packages\arrow\parser.py", line 346, in parse
    return self._build_datetime(parts)
  File "C:\Users\enricojr\Projects\python-lox\.venv\lib\site-packages\arrow\parser.py", line 701, in _build_datetime
    datetime(
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
>>> arrow.__version__
'1.2.2'
>>>
```

Documentation states that "MMM" is the token for abbreviated months, but it's expecting a number from 1 - 12 instead. Am I using the tokens incorrectly, or is something else wrong here?

Python version: 3.10.4
Arrow version: 1.2.2
Operating System: Windows 10, and locale is reported by Python as `en_US`.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> windll = ctypes.windll.kernel32
>>> windll.GetUserDefaultUILanguage()
1033
```

(1033 is en_US)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your minutes in the format string:

`myformat = "MMM D, YYYY @ H:MM A"`

The minutes should should be `mm`, lowercase, the problem is there, not with `MMM`.

So when you do `arrow.get("Aug 2, 2022 @ 11:37 PM", myformat)`, it's complaining that 37 is outside of 1 and 12.

https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

- Month token: MM 01, 02, 03 ... 11, 12
- Minute token: mm 00, 01, 02 … 58, 59

Also, going forward, beware 'July' and 'Aug' are different formats.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much! (also thanks for the heads up on the "July" vs "Aug" thing, it was just a typo on my part the source data is correctly abbreviated, I appreciate it anyways)